# how to build ajtcl 15.09a on stm32f4discovery board

Tags: stm32f4discovery, alljoyn

I'm building Alljoyn platform on stm32f407VGT6 board, but i don't know how to use libraries to build. Anyone has suggest for me

- List item

? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- The first: we will add librarys STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0 Click [here](https://www.fshare.vn/file/XJL5NJIMBFW1)! and FreeRTOSV8.0.0 Click [here](https://www.fshare.vn/file/NMZQI3LG6AO7)!
  then we change **os.environ.get('AJ_STM_SRC_DIR')** into **../librarys STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0** and change **os.environ.get('AJ_FREE_RTOS_DIR')** into **'../FreeRTOSV8.0.0/FreeRTOS/'**, and one important thing is: in file aj_target_platform.c comment lines number 360->369 and line number 376
- Scons :  scons WS=off VARIANT=debug TARG=freertos-stm32